# dynamic file name and highlighting rows

Tags: vba, excel

with the good help of you guys at stackoverflow i managed to complete one portion of what i am trying to accomplish however i have 2 other portion which.. i tried for abit but being how bad i am at this i can't figure it out

what this is supposed to do is from 2 workbook to_update_example_1 it will search for the same name on column H compare with column H of Purchasing list, if found copy the QTY column G(to_update_example_1) to column F(purchasing list) which the code does perfectly.

i'm just trying to know if fail to update then highlight the row which failed and on column O or P write a text "item not found"

and also when we download our to_update list from our online the file name is dynamic although sheet name is static, is there a way to avoid going to the coding end to change the file name instead maybe input the filename on macro run or select file or something...

Thanks in advance!

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro1()
    Dim cell As Range, FindRng As Range, ErrorRng As Range

    Dim purchListSht As Worksheet
    Set purchListSht = Workbooks("Purchasing List.xls").Worksheets("Liltots") '(change "purchaseData" to your actual "purchase" sheet name)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    With Workbooks("to_update_example_1").Sheets("GoodsSelInfo_LIST_SELL_INVENTOR") ' reference your "source" worksheet in "source" workbookworkbook (change "SourceData" to your actual "source" sheet name)
            For Each cell In .Range("H1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants) ' loop through referenced "source" sheet column "H" not empty cells
            Set FindRng = purchListSht.Columns("H").Find(What:=cell.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns) ' try finding current cell content in "purchase" sheet column "G"
            If Not FindRng Is Nothing Then '<-- make sure Find was successful finding vVal1
             FindRng.Offset(, -2).Value = cell.Offset(, -1).Value ' if successful, write the value of the cell one column left of the current cell to the cell two columns to the left of found cell
        Else ' raise some kind of notification
            MsgBox "Unable to find " & cell, vbInformation
        End If

        Next
    End With
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need a little change inside your `For Each cell` loop:

```
    For Each cell In .Range("H1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants) ' loop through referenced "source" sheet column "H" not empty cells
        Set FindRng = purchListSht.Columns("G").Find(What:=cell.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns) ' try finding current cell content in "purchase" sheet column "G"
        If FindRng Is Nothing Then ' if no match found
            cell.Offset(, 7).Value = "item not found" ' write in column "O" of current cell row
            Intersect(.UsedRange, cell.EntireRow).Interior.ColorIndex = 6 ' yellow highlight current cell row
        Else ' if match found
            FindRng.Offset(, -2).Value = cell.Offset(, -1).Value ' write the value of the cell one column left of the current cell to the cell two columns to the left of found cell
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: in case anyone else might be looking at this ans theres a little typo   Intersect(.usedrange, cell.EntireRow).Interior.ColorIndex = 6 ' yellow highlight current cell row
        Else ' if match found